# How to delete file references from Textmate project permanently?

Tags: textmate

I created a textmate project for a django app I'm working on, and I want to permanently remove the reference to "venv" folder from the project, but everytime I remove the "venv" folder from the project (deleting the reference), everytime I open the project again, I have to repeat that process. How do I just permanently remove a file/folder reference?

Having this "venv" folder in the project makes my project-searching A LOT slower.

Comment: So you right click on the folder and click remove reference?

Comment: When I close and re-open the project, the references are still there. I want the project to persistently save the fact that I removed the references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your project has a reference to a folder that has the 'venv' folder in it.  Textmate is going to refresh the contents of the referenced folder every time it gains focus, including the 'venv' folder.  This is helpful when you want it to see newly added folders, not so helpful when you want to exclude things.

While not the most fine-grained fix, you can exclude folders as noted in [the docs](http://manual.macromates.com/en/working_with_multiple_files):

> **2.1.2 Filtering Unwanted Files**
>
> When using folder references, you may want to have certain files or folders excluded from the project. This can be done by changing the file and folder patterns found in Preferences → Advanced → Folder References.
>
> These are regular expressions which are matched against the full path of each file and folder. If the pattern does match the item, it is included, otherwise it is excluded. To reverse that, so that items which match are excluded from the project, prefix the pattern with an exclamation point (!).
>
> The patterns are only used when creating new folder references. For existing folder references one can select the folder reference in the project drawer and use the info button (a circled letter I) in the project drawer to edit the patterns.
>
> *The complexity of this system will be addressed in a future release.*

Adding 'venv' to that regex should keep it from (ever) being included.

Comment: Interesting. How would I be able to do that? My regex right now is:
"!.*/(\.[^/]*|CVS|_darcs|_MTN|\{arch\}|blib|.*~\.nib|.*\.(framework|app|pbproj|pbxproj|xcode(proj)?|bundle))$"
I'm not quite sure how to add venv to this

Comment: I figured it out. I changed the modified the default regex to "!.*/(\.[^/]*|CVS|venv|_darcs|_MTN|\{arch\}|blib|.*~\.nib|.*\.(framework|app|pbproj|pbxproj|xcode(proj)?|bundle))$" and then created a new Textmate project with the same project folder. Thanks!

Comment: Poking around a bit more, the project file itself also appears to have a copy of that regex inside it, so you might be able to change it on a per-project basis instead of globally.

Comment: @blahdiblah how to change it per project?, i was able to update regex  in settings, but these changes applies to all projects